# decoding a file with .msr extension

Tags: python, encoding, byte, decode

I am trying to decode a file with .msr extension. This is the data file for the old version of the program "PHYWE measure 4". This program is for measuring various physical experiments. It has a completely incomprehensible encoding, I went through all the available encodings in notepad++ and tried to read bytes using python. The first line contains data like this:

```
\x19\x05\x06\x07\x08\tmeasure45 FileFormat\x04\x00\x01\x00X\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\xfc\x1d\xba\x13\x00\x00\x00\x004\xa1\xd3\xdf\xb7\xca\xe5@\xa4\xf8\xb8\x13\xe4\x17\xb9\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\xa3\xf3\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xa4p}?\n
```

Can you please tell me if it is possible to get numerical data in my case?

Answer (score 0):

The PHYWE measure software uses a proprietary (binary) file format, but you can download the software for free from the PHYWE website:
https://repository.curriculab.net/files/software/setupm.exe

In the measure application, you can use the option "Export data..." to either save the numerical data as text file or copy the values to the clipboard.